# What's a good word for "OwnType"?

Tags: meaning

I am creating a kitesurfing website, and I have a problem.

Explanation:

- There is a table with the columns `Title, OwnType, Type of equipment, DateCreated`
- Entries in the `OwnType` column may be 'My' or 'Found' or 'Lost'. Entries in the `Type of equipment` column are `Board`, `Footwear`, `Board Accessories`.
- User 1, "Adam" enters a piece of equipment which he owns
- User 2, "Dave" enters a piece of equipment which he has found
- There is a search page which User 3, "Anna" uses to discover who has lost or has found a particular kind of equipment; for instance, `Board nobile 2013 size 10m`. Her search returns these two records.

**First question.**

What English term would be good to display for `OwnType`?

**Second question**

What English terms would be good for the values displayed in the column `OwnType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something like this, a good heading would be "Item Status". (You could come up with any number of appropriate headings, but I think that one works well enough.) The idea is that the values in this column will tell you the current status of the item entered.

As for the values, I would use "Owned" (I have this and it's mine), "Lost" (I had this but I can't find it), and "Found" (I have this but it's not mine). These seem to be the clearest ways to express the states of the item. (You could also add a "Wishlist" category if you want; "I don't have this but I want it.")

As an aside, I'm not sure I understand what useful information would go in the "Title" column. Also a column with the name of the poster would likely be useful; if Anna lost the item, when she gets her search results she needs to know that it was Dave who found it. Otherwise how will she get it back?

Comment: Thanks. It's good suggestion. I did not say the truth about the columns, I have last column is 'send email'